# Auto-application to `()` is deprecated. Supply the empty argument list `()` explicitly to invoke method fetch,

Tags: phantom-dsl

an interesting behaviour in the Scala compiler, prepared queries that use the “IN” operator will require special binding at compile time, called ListValue.

```
trait InSelectPreparedExamples extends db.Connector {

  lazy val selectInExample = db.entries.select.where(_.car in ?).prepareAsync()

  // This is a select * query, selecting the entire record
  def selectFromList(values: List[UUID]): Future[List[CarMetric]] = {
    selectInExample.flatMap(_.bind(ListValue(values)).fetch)
  }

  // We can use also use a vargargs style method call to achieve the same goal.  
  def selectFromArgs(args: UUID*): Future[List[CarMetric]] = {
    selectInExample.flatMap(_.bind(ListValue(args: _*)).fetch)
  }
}
```

when i use this ListValue i have got warn

```
**
warn] or remove the empty argument list from its definition (Java-defined methods are exempt).
[warn] In Scala 3, an unapplied method like this will be eta-expanded into a function.
[warn]     selectInExample.flatMap(_.bind(ListValue(values)).fetch())
[warn]                                   ^
```

scalaVersion := "2.13.4"
libraryDependencies += "com.outworkers" %% "phantom-dsl" % "2.59.0"

how can fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 2.12 and below the following syntax was valid without any warnings

```
def test(): A = ???

test // is automatically expanded to test()
```

However from Scala 2.13 this gives a warning

```
Auto-application to `()` is deprecated. Supply the empty argument list `()` explicitly to invoke method test
```

And in Scala 3 that syntax would be [illegal](https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/guides/migration/incompat-dropped-features.html#auto-application).

In your case the `phantom-dsl` library has a class with methods with empty parameter list - https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/blob/v2.59.0/phantom-dsl/src/main/scala/com/outworkers/phantom/builder/primitives/Primitives.scala#L166

once they fix the [bug](https://github.com/outworkers/phantom/issues/923) you already reported the warnings should be gone.